# Kraken.js: How i access the configuration data

Tags: javascript, node.js, kraken.js

How i access my custom configuration at the configurations files ( config.js | development.js )?

config.js | development.js :

```
{

    "database": {

        "user": "user123",
        "password": "pass123"

   },

  "express": {
       "view cache": false,
       "view engine": "js",
       "views": "path:./.build/templates"
  },

[...]
```

My database connection file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function Database() {

    console.log( conf.database );

};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kraken loads the configuration asynchronously during it's bootstrap, and once it's done, emits a `start` event which you can listen for via the main express `app`.  Within there you can gain access to the configuration.  So for instance, if you added this to your application's `index.js`:

```
app.on('start', function() {
    console.log(app.kraken.get('database'));
});
```

You would see (on the console):

```
{ user: 'user123', password: 'pass123' }
```

Because this is available *only* after Kraken has completed it's bootstrap process, you'll need to factor that in when loading up your database connection file (perhaps connect to the database from within the `start` event listener).